# This donation progress bar designed in HTML/CSS breaks when bar is at 90%+. How do i get the text to stay in place or shrink as the bar is increased?

Tags: html, css

CCS beginner here and first time poster to stack overflow. I know the basics of how CSS works and can figure out how to change colors,fonts, and basics like that or but not enough to make major changes on my own...

Found this great [Donation Progress Bar](https://codepen.io/stemlund/pen/Bkvyj) on codepen.io built with HTML/CSS (click link for code and easy to view preview) that I added to client's squarespace site. I mostly figured out how to control it but either i'm doing it wrong or it has issues because when changing the keyframes to show 90% progress, the bar breaks because the text is pushed down to the next line.

How do i edit the code so that it works no matter what the progress is? Either by making the text just float on top of the actual bar, or maybe making it shrink as it gets closer to the goal? I'm open to any suggestions or other free options. I think it looks great and would work well as a manual option but i need to be able to control it.

The portion I've been editing to get it to move to 90% is the very bottom snippet (and the browser specific ones to match):

```css
@keyframes progress-bar {
    from { width: 0%; }
    to { width: 50%; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap` to `.progress-bg h3.goal`

It will still jump out of the progress bar at higher percentages, but at least it won't look as broken when it does.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.progress-bg {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 65%;
  height: 78px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url("http://www.atsu.edu/stlclinic/images/progress-bar-bg.jpg") repeat;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 78px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /* fallback */
  background-color: #1c314a;
  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1c314a), to(#27425f));
  /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1c314a, #27425f);
  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1c314a, #27425f);
  /* IE 10 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1c314a, #27425f);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1c314a, #27425f);
}

.progress-bg h3.goal,
.progress-bg h3.raised {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 78px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}

.progress-bg h3.raised {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 14px 25px 0 50px;
  padding: 0 25px 0 0;
}

.progress-bg h3.goal {
  color: #b2b2b2;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

body .progress-bg h3.raised {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 4s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-animation: fadein 4s;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-animation: fadein 4s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 4s;
  /* Opera */
  animation: fadein 4s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari and Chrome */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

​
/* Opera */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

​ .progress-bg h3.goal {
  float: right;
  display: none;
  padding: 0 25px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body .progress-bg div {
  -webkit-animation: progress-bar 2s ease forwards;
  -moz-animation: progress-bar 2s ease forwards;
  -o-animation: progress-bar 2s ease forwards;
  animation: progress-bar 2s ease forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes progress-bar {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes progress-bar {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@keyframes progress-bar {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bg">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <h3 class="raised">$50,000&nbsp;raised</h3>
  </div>

  <h3 class="goal">Goal: $100,000</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That does look better to the point where I am comfortable using it on the site. I can't imagine where the $100,000 would go when the bar is that small anyway so I think this would make sense. ***Edit* This is actually a great looking solution! Thank you so much!**

Comment: Do you have a similar solution for the "raised" when the bar is super small like 1-10%? I was so focussed on the end i didn't realize the beginning was an issue too. Thanks so much by the way! Trying to learn slowly on my own as I work on more web projects through my job.

Comment: Actually, I just realized i can't see it because it's white on white. I can just change the color in the beginning stages. Thanks again for your help!.

Comment: No problem, glad you could sort it. Doesn't look like whoever created this tested it with low/high values!

Comment: They didnt test it on mobile either. For now im just going to hide it on mobile and try to tweak as i go.